# C# mongodb array sort and limit

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there any possible way of sorting a data inside a document and only fetch part of it?

For example:

```
public class PingPong
{
    //some other data except Ranks
    //...
    //...
    public List<UserIdRank> Ranks;
}

public class UserIdRank
{
    public ObjectId UserId;
    public int Rank;
}
```

is there a way to fetch the top 5 users rank and ONLY them in some use or `Sort` and `Projection`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question. Are you asking if it's possible to get top 5 users by their rank?

Comment: @Saleem yes..thats exactly what i need

Comment: How does your MongoDB documents look like? Please post few.

Comment: I was actually struggling for some days with acessing and updating of embedded Arrays of Objects. At the current state of the C# driver it is very cumbersome and due to lack of documentaion I didn't manage all what I needed so I changed my design to have two collections with a reference foreign key in my former array members.

Comment: @Thomas i know..thought about it..but this way im losing my capabilities of atomic updates

Comment: Best will be to add your Mongo document to your question as Saleem asked for.
What do you mean with need for atomic udates in your app scenario?

Comment: I described the objects as classes. Why you all need the document itself?